# models.DoesNotExist - web application using python flask

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, flask-wtforms, pymodm

everyone. anyone. Below is my models.py file, where I've created a table in the database

```
class Staff(UserMixin, MongoModel):
    full_name = fields.CharField(required=True, blank=False)
    job_position = fields.CharField(required=True, blank=False)
    email = fields.EmailField(required=True, blank=False)
    password = fields.CharField(required=True, blank=False)

    def get_id(self):
        return str(self.pk)
```

I am using flask-login for my login authentication

```
 login_manager = LoginManager()
 login_manager.login_view = 'login'
 login_manager.init_app(app)


 @login_manager.user_loader
 def load_user(staff_id):
     staff = Staff.objects.get({"_id": ObjectId(staff_id)})
     return staff
```

This is the route to the login page

```
@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        email = form.email.data
        password = form.email.data
        remember = form.remember.data
        staff = Staff.objects.raw({"email": email, "password": password})
        if staff.count() == 0:
            return "Invalid email or password"
        login_user(staff.first())
        remember = remember
        return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
    return render_template("login.html", form=form)
```

It returns a model.DoesNotExist, which clearly exists but I must be doing something wrong

Comment: You probably haven't done a [migration](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to convert the python model to an actual database change.

Comment: I have. There is a signup page that works and a different web app entirely, but this is the first time I am using the flask wtforms for my client's login. The debug is giving the line (def load_user) as the problem, which I have instantiated.